# How to create a hashed dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Given the following data (myinput.txt):

```
A  q,y,h
B  y,f,g
C  n,r,q
### more rows
```

How can I convert it into such data structure in R?

```
$A
 [1] "q" "y" "h" 
$B
 [1] "y" "f" "g"
$C
 [1] "n" "r" "q"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've assumed this as your data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="q,y,h
y,f,g
n,r,q", header=FALSE, sep=",", row.names=c("A", "B", "C"))
```

If you want an automatic method:

```
as.list(as.data.frame((t(dat)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))

## $A
## [1] "q" "y" "h"
##
## $B
## [1] "y" "f" "g"
## 
## $C
## [1] "n" "r" "q"
```

Another couple of methods which work are:

```
lapply(apply(dat, 1, list), "[[", 1)

unlist(apply(dat, 1, list), recursive=FALSE)
```

Comment: @sebastian-c: thanks a lot. Is there a way I can make 'dat' automatically recognize the row.names?
i.e. not assigning it.

Comment: @neversaint I just did that to recreate your data. I should have used `row.names=1`, so an example would be: `read.csv("dat.csv", row.names=1)`. You might also want to add either `colClasses="character"` or `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` into the `read.table`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a bit of `readLines` `strsplit` and regex to account for breaking the names off the start:

```
dat <- readLines(textConnection("A  q,y,h
B  y,f,g
C  n,r,q"))

result <- lapply(strsplit(dat,"\\s{2}|,"),function(x) x[2:length(x)])
names(result) <- gsub("^(.+)\\s{2}.+$","\\1",dat)

> result
$A
[1] "q" "y" "h"

$B
[1] "y" "f" "g"

$C
[1] "n" "r" "q"
```

or with less regex and more steps:

```
result <- strsplit(dat,"\\s{2}|,")
names(result) <- lapply(result,"[",1)
result <- lapply(result,function(x) x[2:length(x)])

> result
$A
[1] "q" "y" "h"

$B
[1] "y" "f" "g"

$C
[1] "n" "r" "q"
```